# Self-Contained Chrome for Selenium Testing

Tags: c#, google-chrome, automated-tests, selenium-chromedriver, self-contained

I would like to know if there is any way to do testing on Chrome **without** actually having to install it (eg. running on machines **without** Chrome). I tried using **PhantomJS** but it did **not** really work. In other words I would like to **embed** Chrome in my app so that the Webdriver will control the **embedded Chrome**. I would **not** like to use Selenium Grid.

## Goal

Run tests on Chrome that is **completely independent** (self-contained or embedded).

Answer (score 0):

Cypress has this feature. When run from the CLI, it will load a baked-in Electron browser, which is a version of Chromium.

https://docs.cypress.io/guides/guides/launching-browsers.html#Electron-Browser

Comment: Thank you for your help, I will try using Cypress.